# Div Layer should be placed over a Flash movie

Tags: css, flash, html

There is a flash application that I want to embed on my site. On top of that flash application there should be a div layer.

But what happens is that the flash movie always appears over the layer.

Can you help me to place the div layer over that flash application?

---

This is the code for the flash application:

```
<object style="width:420px;height:266px">
    <param name="movie" value="http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v1/IssuuViewer.swf?mode=embed&amp;layout=http%3A%2F%2Fskin.issuu.com%2Fv%2Flight%2Flayout.xml&amp;showFlipBtn=true&amp;documentId=100702013356-a81e1742e2dc46e296b57f933885cfb7&amp;docName=victor_online_201007_e&amp;username=Victor_online_English&amp;loadingInfoText=Victor%20by%20Hasselblad%20(07%2F2010)&amp;et=1284505268784&amp;er=62" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/><param name="menu" value="false" />
    <embed src="http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v1/IssuuViewer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" menu="false" style="width:420px;height:266px" flashvars="mode=embed&amp;layout=http%3A%2F%2Fskin.issuu.com%2Fv%2Flight%2Flayout.xml&amp;showFlipBtn=true&amp;documentId=100702013356-a81e1742e2dc46e296b57f933885cfb7&amp;docName=victor_online_201007_e&amp;username=Victor_online_English&amp;loadingInfoText=Victor%20by%20Hasselblad%20(07%2F2010)&amp;et=1284505268784&amp;er=62" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. Try setting the wmode of the flash movie to "transparent"
2. Wrap the embedded flash movie in a `div` and give it a lower z-index than the content div.